# Extend rows of hardcoded table with formula Power BI

Tags: powerbi, row, formula, powerquery

I manually (hardcoded) made a table with 2 rows, which are my starting values, in Power BI:
[image]

Now I want to extend the amount of rows of this table but I want the next value to be: 1.3% - (1.3% * 5%) = 1.24%
Further, I want the row after this row to contain the value: 1.24% - (1.24% * 5%) = 1.17% and so on.

Does someone know how to do this in Power BI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh this was pretty stupid of myself, I forgot to mention that the values are percentages. So 1.3% - (1.3% * 5%) = 1.24% and 1.24% - (1.24% * 5%) = 1.17% etc. I've updated the question now too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are doing 1.3*(1-.05)^x where x=row number, so...

```
let  Source = {0..100}, //edit 100 higher for more rows
Process = List.Transform(Source, each 1.3*Number.Power((1-.05),_)), //1.3*(1-.05)^x
Output = Table.FromColumns({Process},{"Name"})
in Output
```

[image]

EDIT:

sample of two columns

```
let  Source = {0..100}, //edit 100 higher for more rows
Process = List.Transform(Source, each 1.3*Number.Power((1-.05),_)), //1.3*(1-.05)^x
Process2 = List.Transform(Source, each -2.5*Number.Power((1-.3),_)), // -2.5*(1-.3)^x
Output = Table.FromColumns({Process}&{Process2},{"First","Second"})
in Output
```

[image]

EDIT2: cumulative sums

```
let  Source = {0..100}, //edit 100 higher for more rows
Process = List.Transform(Source, each List.Sum(let a=_ in List.Transform({0..a}, each 1.3*Number.Power((1-.05),_)))),
Process2 = List.Transform(Source, each List.Sum(let a=_ in List.Transform({0..a}, each -2.5*Number.Power((1-.3),_)))),
Output = Table.FromColumns({Process}&{Process2},{"First","Second"})
in Output
```

or

```
let  Source = {0..100}, //edit 100 higher for more rows
Process = List.Transform(Source, each 1.3*Number.Power((1-.05),_)), //1.3*(1-.05)^x
Process2 = List.Transform(Source, each -2.5*Number.Power((1-.3),_)), // -2.5*(1-.3)^x
Output = Table.FromColumns({Process}&{Process2},{"First","Second"}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Output, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "FirstCum", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[First],[Index]+1))),
#"Added Cum Total2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Cum Total", "SecondCum", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[Second],[Index]+1)))
in #"Added Cum Total2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I haven't had time to check yet. But I do have a follow up question. Let's say I want to have not 1 column but 2 columns where the first one is like I described above and the second one has the formula: -2.5*(1-.3)^x. How would you do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to anger you. I've now had time to test it and it works flawless, thanks! Do you know if it's possible to make a second column but then with the formula: -2.5*(1-.3)^x ?

Comment: It's working perfect! Thank you horseyride!

Comment: Added cumulative sum version